# CAN Error Counters behaviour

Tags: can

Can someone explain how the nodes behave when an error is detected by one or more nodes?
I have tried understanding it from the CAN Spec but it seems complicated.
When do the Transmit and Receive error counters increment and by what values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counters are updated as follows:

1. When a receiver detects an error, the rx_count will be
   increased by 1, except when the detected error was a bit
   error during the sending of an active error flag or an
   overload flag.
2. When a receiver detects a dominant bit as the first bit
   after sending an error flag, the rx_count will be increased
   by 8.
3. When a transmitter sends an error flag, the tx_count is
   increased by 8.
   Exception 1: If the transmitter is error passive and detects
   an ack error because of not detecting a dominant ack and
   does not detect a dominant bit while sending its passive
   error flag.
   Exception 2: If the transmitter sends an error flag because a
   stuff error occurred during arbitration whereby the stuff bit
   is located before the RTR bit, and should have been
   recessive, and has been sent as recessive but monitored as
   dominant.
4. If a transmitter detects a bit error while sending an active
   error flag or an overload flag, the tx_count is increased
   by 8.
5. If a receiver detects a bit error while sending an active
   error flag or an overload flag the rx_count is increased
   by 8.
6. Any node accepts up to 7 consecutive dominant bits after
   sending an active or passive error flag or an overload flag.
   After detecting the 14th consecutive dominant bit (in the
   case of an active error flag or an overload flag), or after
   detecting the 8th consecutive dominant bit following a
   passive error flag, and after each sequence of additional 8
   consecutive dominant bits every transmitter increases its
   tx_count by 8 and every receiver increases its rx_count
   by 8.
7. After the successful transmission of a message (getting
   ack and no error until end of frame is finished) tx_count is
   decreased by 1 unless it was already 0.
8. After the successful reception of a message (reception
   without error up to the ack slot and the successful sending
   of the ack bit), rx_count is decreased by 1 if it was between
   1 and 127. If rx_count was 0 it stays 0, and if it was greater
   than 127, it will be set to a value between 119 and 127.
   Note: If a node is the only one on the bus (or during startup
   the only one that has become active), and it transmits a
   message, it will get an acknowledgement error, and will
   retransmit the message. This may lead to that node going to
   error passive mode, but not to it becoming bus off

[Reference for the above points](http://www.ijetae.com/files/Volume4Issue3/IJETAE_0314_66.pdf)